# Async and parallel execution functions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have a functions:

```
int f1(int a)
{
    return a;
}

int f2(int a)
{
    return a*2;
}
```

I want execute functions async and parallel, waiting results and summing then results. I can use code

```
 var result1 = Task.Run(() => f1(5));
 var result2 = Task.Run(() => f2(10));

 await Task.WhenAll(result1, result2);

 int result = result1.Result + result2.Result;
```

It's cool. But what do, if my functions work with callbacks

```
void f1(Action<int> action, int a)
{
    action.Invoke(a);
}

void f2(Action<int> action, int a)
{
    a = a*2;
    action.Invoke(a);
}

f1(result => Console.WriteLine("result1 = {0}", result), 5);
f2(result => Console.WriteLine("result2 = {0}", result), 10);
```

I can't rewrite this functions, this functions using in others code. In this case I can solve the problem that my code didn't resemble hell?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem? The callbacks will be synchronous within their respective tasks... is that what you're asking?

Comment: I don't know how to execute these functions then summing results. I can only execute second function in callback first function. But it not be parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
var tcs2 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

f1( (x) =>  { tcs1.SetResult(x);  }, 5);
f2( (x) =>  { tcs2.SetResult(x);  }, 10);

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tcs1.Task, tcs2.Task);
int result = results[0] + results[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `TaskCompletionSource` class to create a task that represents the completion of a callback-based asynchronous method (or an event based asynchronous method, or any other non-`Task` based method of asynchronous out there):

```
var f1CompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
var f2CompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
Task.Run(() => foo.f1(n => f1CompletionSource.TrySetResult(n), 5));
Task.Run(() => foo.f2(n => f2CompletionSource.TrySetResult(n), 10));

await Task.WhenAll(f1CompletionSource.Task,
    f2CompletionSource.Task);

int result = f1CompletionSource.Task.Result +
    f2CompletionSource.Task.Result;
```

It's unclear here whether you want `f1` and `f2` to be called through `Task.Run`.  The methods you provided did their work synchronously, not asynchronously, but if the actual methods you're modeling here do their work asynchronously, then there's no need for the `Task.Run`.